# Grails 2.1.1 submit button does not work with IE once deployed

Tags: grails, internet-explorer-11, gsp

I have a simple form which selects a range of dates, and then I click a submit button and it lists some data between the date ranges.

Everything works fine when running it in test mode under Netbeans, and everything works fine once deployed except when using IE (version 11).  If I use IE then clicking the submit button has no effect at all.

But it works with IE when running on my local machine under Netbeans. As soon as I deploy to my tomcat server IE stops working, but Firefox and Chrome continue to work fine.

I'm not sure where to start looking. HTML? Tomcat? Grails? IE? OS? Java?

I'm running Windows 7, Grails 2.1.1, Java 7, Netbeans 7.2, and I'm deploying to Tomcat6 under ubuntu 14.04 LTS

My Html goes something like :-

```
<fieldset class="form">
<g:form action="list" method="GET">
  <div class="fieldcontain">
    </br>
    <table class="campl-table-bordered campl-table-striped campl-table" style="width: auto;">
      <thead>
          <tr>
          <th style="width: auto;">Start Date</th>                              
          <td><g:datePicker name="datefrom" value="${params.datefrom}" precision="day" years="${2012..2099}"  noSelection="['':'']"/></td>
          </tr>                                  
          <tr>
          <th style="width: auto;">End Date</th>                                   
          <td><g:datePicker name="dateto" value="${params.dateto}" precision="day" years="${2012..2099}"  noSelection="['':'']"/></td>
          </tr>          
      </thead>
    </table>

      </br>
      <button class="btn btn-inverse" >Submit   </button>       
       </br>
      </br>
      </br>
       Download to CSV <g:checkBox name="myCheckbox" value="${false}" /> 
  </div>
</g:form> 
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Start at the developer console of the browser. Make sure, that you show all levels of output and see if the browser complains about something.  Then click the button and see if a request is made.

Comment: Ok, I found the solution.  I needed to use the grails tag g:actionSubmit  rather than just using an HTML submit button. I guess Chrome and Firefox are more sympathetic to idiots like me, whereas IE is stricter to adhering to standards perhaps?  Anyway, it works all round now using the correct Grails tag.

Comment: sorry, for fullness I replaced  <button class="btn btn-inverse" >Submit   </button>      with     <g:actionSubmit value="Submit" action="list" />